# In Dart, how to reference a Type that contains generic parameters

Tags: generics, dart

I'm trying to get a `Type` of a class with generics. Basically I want this code below:

```
Type myType = List<String>;
```

But this obviously doesn't work.

I know I can do the following:

```
// indirect from an instance
List<String> myList = methodCall();
Type varType = myList;

// directly without generics
Type stringType = String;
```

But how to make it direct from the definition with generics?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a `Type` object for any type using a function like

```dart
Type typeOf<T>() => T;
```

Then you can write:

```dart
Type myType = typeOf<List<String>>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is what I was looking for. Although, how weird it is that there's no direct language feature for that (forcing us to create separate functions for it.

Comment: How do you use it then? Can you put up a simple working example on https://dartpad.dartlang.org/dart ?

Answer (score 0):

If running on the VM this may be what you're looking for:

```
void main() {
  print(myType);
}

Type myType = List<String>().runtimeType;
```

That gives `List<String>`.

When compiled to JS, though, that same thing outputs `JSArray<String>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for a generic answer, not specifically the List<String>, with that @lm answer seems to be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Since [Dart 2.15](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-15-7e7a598e508a), you don't need to use `typeOf` anymore to work with type literals
with generics:

```dart
var x = List;                   // Already supported
var y = typeOf<List<String>>(); // Pre-2.15 workaround
var z = List<String>;           // New in 2.15
```